# Upload images to portfolio using Server Side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, upload, ssjs

I have a simple html file upload page, an example snippet of the code below.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="<ExactTarget page with ssjs file handling>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I can pass the post request onto an exact target landing page but can i then retrieve the file on the landing page using ssjs? And then upload that to a portfolio folder? I can't really find anything in the documentation or perhaps i have not looked in the correct places?

The final goal is to upload an image from my local machine to an ET portfolio folder.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to need a little bit more information.  How are you getting the file?  A jquery plug-in?  Are loading on one landing page and posting to another?  Or is the first landing page external to ET?

We need to figure out how to get a URL to that image, and go from there.

Comment: @Timothy This webpage is hosted on exact target and will post to another webpage on exact target, i use the html input with the type file to allow the user to upload a image from their local machine, when the user clicks the submit button this should essentially send a post request(request should contain  the image they uploaded) to another exact target page and **this page should use ssjs to get the image from the  request and upload the image to a ET portfolio folder**. The part in bold is what i am needing help with.

Comment: Could you get a solution for this?